# gRPC streaming through AWS NLB

Tags: amazon-web-services, grpc, nlb, aws-nlb

I'm trying to understand how AWS NLB can handle gRPC streaming connections behind the scenes. I know that gRPC streaming keep connection open for long times but AWS NLB has a connection timeout, if I'm not wrong, it means I can't keep the same connection more than {n} seconds.

Can you explain to me how is it possible?